# Form submit button won't work

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I can see no problems with my code but whenever I push the `submit` button, nothing happens:

```
<form id = "form_signin_containers" action = "" method = "post">
    <input type = "text" name = "si_idnumber" placeholder = "ID Number" required/>
    <input type = "password" name = "si_password" placeholder = "Password" required/>
    <input type = "submit" name = "si_submit" value = "    sign in    ">
</form>
```

I tried adding an isset button to the php code above my html code to test it out:

```
if(isset($_POST['si_submit'])) {
  header("Location:home.php");
}
```

When I press the submit button it still won't work. I also noticed, since I put a `<...required/>` on all the textbox, if I should click the submit button, it would notify me if the textboxes are empty right? But still when I leave the textboxes blank and presses the submit button, it won't do anything, it won't  even tell me that the textboxes are empty. As if the button is dead.

**UPDATE**

I have this `javascript` that I placed right before the `</body>` that will make the page scroll smoothly whenever I click an anchor button. 
 Sample of my anchor buttons:

```
<form id = "form_createaccount_button" action="#createchooserblink">
    <input type="submit" value="  create account  " />
</form>
```

The JS:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
     $('input').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var hash = $(this).parent('form').attr('action');
     var target = $(hash);
     target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + hash.slice(1) +']');
     if (target.length) {
       $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: target.offset().top
       }, 1000);
     }

 });
 });
</script>
```

Could this be affecting the login forms?

Comment: either your browser is old, or there is some javascript interrupting how these things work. `required` has to work

Comment: @JapanGuy yeah I just posted an update regarding js that I used... could this be the problem?

Comment: using `if(isset($_POST['si_submit'])) {` in the same file?

Comment: @devpro Yeah.. I do this often times. Is this a bad thing? I  also feel insecure about it too. I used it to connect my html button to my php code.

Comment: move on to Framework, will help u more

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, your JavaScript is preventing form submission:

```
$('input').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     // ...
```

Clicking the submit button triggers that click handler, and preventing the default action prevents form submission.

You could specifically leave the `name="si_submit"` button out of that by adding `:not([name=si_submit])`:

```
$('input:not([name=si_submit])').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     // ...
```

...but I think instead of doing that, I'd probably use a class or something on the "anchor buttons" (or not use the "anchor buttons" at all), and add that class instead. E.g.:

```
<form id = "form_createaccount_button" action="#createchooserblink">
    <input type="submit" class="anchor-button" value="  create account  " />
</form>
```

and:

```
$('input.anchor-button').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     // ...
```

Comment: second one is great ... :)

Comment: Yeah Thanks! I just realized this too. I tried deleting the whole javascript and the forms work. Is there an alternative way or a modification of the JS that will make the forms work and would also trigger the smooth-scroll ?

Comment: `form.submit()` @Dranreb

Comment: @Dranreb: The `:not` or class options in the answer allow your "anchor buttons" to keep working without interfering with form submission.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
<form id="form_signin_containers" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">
<input type="text" name="si_idnumber" placeholder="ID Number" required>
<input type="password" name="si_password" placeholder="Password" required>
<input type="submit" value="sign in">
</form>
```